# Eclipse .jazzlock save could not be completed

Tags: eclipse, locking, jazz

Eclipse loaded fine and was able to make any changes I could, but suddenly When I try to make change and save a file I get the following error:

```
Save could not be completed. try file > Save as... if the problem persists

Reason:
Unable to lock file c:\workspace\ws\.jazz5\.jazzlock
```

Answer (score 3):

Delete the >jazzlock file in from your home workspace folder and restart your eclipse. It worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this when Eclipse hasn't closed cleanly.  It can leave a process still running.
Close all instances of Eclipse then look for extra's still running in Task Manager/Processes and stop them.

Comment: if you try to manually delete the .jazzlock file on Windows and you can't because it's in use by another process (even though you've already closed Eclipse), look for other running Eclipse/Java processes and kill them, then restart. This fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

Change the "Load repository" folder under build definitions and re do the build.
Deleting the .jazzlock file and shutting the eclipse to do the build, would work only when things are done "headless"ly.

Thanks.